# Change mysql bind-address from command line in Vagrant

Tags: mysql, bash, vagrant

I am setting up a new vagrant box for a NodeJS project. For the database I will be using MySQL. I have setup a provisioning script to install everything I need and it all works great apart from accessing MySQL from the host machine (Using Sequel Pro). I have it working but I have to edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file in order to comment out the bind-address line.

Is there anyway to do this on the command line so I can add it to the provisioning script? If this is possible then any other dev that I share the project with would only need to do `vagrant up` and have everything ready to go.

Below are the parts of my script relevant to the MySQL setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
DBHOST=localhost
DBNAME=vagrant
DBUSER=vagrant
DBPASSWD=test123

# Update packages
apt-get update

# Install MySQL
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $DBPASSWD"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $DBPASSWD"
apt-get install -y mysql-server
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME"
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "CREATE USER '$DBUSER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$DBPASSWD'"
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $DBNAME.* TO '$DBUSER'@'localhost'"
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "CREATE USER '$DBUSER'@'10.0.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY '$DBPASSWD'"
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $DBNAME.* TO '$DBUSER'@'10.0.2.2'"
echo "Installed MySQL"
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the bound address? Your bind address is the local interface your service is listening for Mysql traffic. Should be 0.0.0.0 (All devices) unless you've got multiple nics and you only want a specific local interface listening.

Comment: Hi Steve, The default bind-address is 127.0.0.1 which stops me from connecting from my host machine. From doing some googling I found that you need to change this to 0.0.0.0 (or comment it out) so I can connect from outside the VM. If the default was 0.0.0.0 I wouldn't need to do this (like you say) but it isn't. Alternatively, is there a way to make the default 0.0.0.0 at the install step?

Comment: You should look into invoking the mysql secure script with prepared inputs and get mysql off of using root as well. GL with your build script sir!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) command from your script

```
apt-get install -y mysql-server
sed -i "s/.*bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
...
```

Note you might need to restart the service to take effect if you provision and do not restart the instance for the 1st use, add this then to your script

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked a treat. I was looking at a workaround to include a copy of my.cnf with the project and copy if with cp at the end of the provisioning but I like this solution much more.

Comment: right, if you have many changes to make, keeping a version of your file and copying during provisioning is easier but if you are just looking for a small change, using some script is better